# Find duplicates where entries within id are duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  class   count   day
 1    2       5      5
 2    2       4      5
 3    2       4      5
 3    2       4      5
 4    2       5      3
 4    1       5      3
 4    2       5      3
```

So I have a query for finding all duplicates based on multiple columns, however, this also returns id's where not all entries are duplicate.
In above example, the query should only show/count id 3, as all the entries with id 3 are duplicate. Even though id 4 also has a duplicate, it should not show as it has another entry that is unique.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well (as table). And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: We will be glad for your feedback ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need rows with `id` where there is no row with the same `id` and unique row values then use `NOT IN` and `HAVING`

```
select *
from your_table t1
where t1.id not in(
  select id
  from your_table
  group by id, class, count, day
  having count(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this one did what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a2536/8

```
select id
from test
group by id 
having count(distinct id,class,count,day) = 1 and count(*)>1
```

you group each rows by id and count how many different row the group has, if the distinct total is 1 and the total row  is > 1 , there is only duplicate rows for this id.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy, a quick note it's a very bad idea to name a column count :

```
    SELECT id, class, `count`,day, COUNT(*)
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY id, class, `count`,day
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

edit : I misread the question so here is my solution :

```
SELECT test.id, test.class, test.count, test.day , count(*), t.countID
FROM (SELECT id, Count(id) AS countID FROM test GROUP BY id ) t
INNER JOIN test on t.id = test.id
GROUP BY test.id, test.class, test.count, test.day
HAVING Count(*) > 1 AND t.countID = count(*)
```

Comment: this query returns the id 4 wich has not full duplicate rows

Comment: I have edited my query please tell us if it's what you want

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this :

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT id,
               Count(id) AS matched
        FROM   test
        GROUP  BY id,
                  class,
                  count,
                  day) t
GROUP  BY id , matched
HAVING Count(id) = 1
       AND matched >= 2
```

There is maybe a more efficient way to do it but it is easier to understand this way, first we group by every column to find duplicate data. Then the first part of the having eliminates the entries that actually have different variants by id and then we keep only the lines that actually only have duplicates.

Edit : compatible with "only_full_group_by" mode

Comment: this answer is working and I was the first to give one, even though it might not be the optimal one I don't think it deserves a downvote...not the first time this happens. People actually downvoting other answers to get theres accepted or something? very nice and encouraging community here.

Comment: Everyone gets weird downvotes without explanation here. I guess it is just due to a large audience. However, if you want to help other people, nobody can stop you :)

Comment: The group by doesn't follow SQL rules in your answer and you will get an error like that "this
is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" if the option is on.

Comment: @DanielE. I tested on a local MySQL database with "sql_mode=only_full_group_by" and I get no errors...

Comment: "#1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 't.matched' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" you can test it here : https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/db_sql.php?db=test_so

Comment: Okay so MySQL Version is different. I edited the request.